# Callback error when calling endpoint function

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, callback

I've received an Node.js api documented with swagger for debbuging. I also have to make some features in it, but I'm having some trouble when calling, in the code, the functions executed when you hit an specific endpoint. To make my self clear:

```js
var getCauById = async function (request, callback) {
    await CauModel.findById(request, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
        } else {
            callback(result);
        }
    });
}
```

Works fine from Swagger UI when I *only* give it the argument of the ID required in the `request` param. Request URL example: `http://localhost:8000/api/cau/{id}` works fine either.

But when I try to call it from another part of the code like this:

```js
const caus = require("../cau")

caus.getCauById("608ff7531ee4d422a201ff5a")
```

then I get `TypeError: callback is not a function. So what's the callback swagger (or the endpoint execution) is providing and I'm missing. I know this is a pretty basic misunderstanding on how APIs and callbacks work, so an explanation would be really appreciated.

Thank you all!

Comment: I think this boils down to an understanding of callbacks. You should do some research on it to understand them better. You can try `caus.getCauById("608ff7531ee4d422a201ff5a", function(result) {console.log(result)})`. You need to pass a function (callback) as the second parameter to `getCauById` because that's what it expects.

Comment: Yep, worked and yep i have to do some research I know. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined getCauById as a function that takes two parameters, request and callback.  But you don't provide "callback" when you call the function.  Callback needs to be a function that does something with err or result.

For example:

```
const caus = require("../cau")
const myCallback = (resultOrError) => console.log(resultOrError);

caus.getCauById("608ff7531ee4d422a201ff5a", myCallback);
```

Comment: Ohh, ok. I didn't realise that the function I had to provide would be the one handling the response. It's obvios know, bit I was bloked. Thank you very much!